# Git - Http - Apache - Windows - fatal: git-http-push failed

Tags: windows, git, apache, http

Thank you for your time to see this thread.

Facing an issue while push to git repository.

Tried multiple solutions and threads in stakeoverflow but all the at last getting following error while push.
error: Cannot access URL `http://localhost:82/Repo1.git/`, return code 22
fatal: git-http-push failed

I am able to clone successfully but not able to push anything to remote repository. Following are the steps I followed:
1. Created a repository inside apache.
2. Clone the same on another location in the same machine and everything working fine.
3. When try to push from the new location getting above error.

Following are my httpd.conf file:

```
 Listen 82

    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs"
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    ScriptAliasMatch \
    "(?x)^/git/(.*/(HEAD|info/refs|objects/(info/[^/]+|[0-9a-f]{2}/[0-9a-f]{38}|pack/pack-[0-9a-f]{40}\.(pack|idx))|git-(upload|receive)-pack))$C:/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend.exe/"$1

    <Directory "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
```

Following are the config file of git repository:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly

[http]
  receivepack = true

[remote "origin"]
url = http://localhost:80/Repo1.git
#url = http://Ishan:ishan@localhost:80/Repo1.git tried this as well but won't work.
```

Git always give following error:

```
error: Cannot access URL http://localhost:82/Repo1.git/, return code
 22
fatal: git-http-push failed
```

Please help me to make it work properly, we are shifting to git and preparing the repositories for testing but I am stuck at this point.

Thanks a lot in advance for all your help!

Thank you,
Ishan

Comment: 1. Don't use dav_module if you're trying to use smart HTTP. 2. You're cloning from port 80, but Apache is listening on port 82?

Comment: Hi Edward,Thank you for your reply. Removed dav_module. and changed port 80 to 82, sorry that was the mistake. But again getting the same error while trying to push.

Comment: Some how problem was unsolved so moved to gitblit and things are working as per requirement with gitblit. I'll look into it and fix the issue when time permits.